# My iOS app and WatchKit app are entirely Swift. Do I need to change "Embedded Content Contains Swift"?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

Currently, it is set to No for all targets: iOS app target, the WatchKit extension and the WatchKit app. Based on this [post](http://www.fiveminutewatchkit.com/blog/2015/4/2/submitting-your-watchkit-app):

If you use Swift in your iPhone app, be sure to set the "Embedded Content Contains Swift" build setting to NO for your frameworks and extensions and YES for your iPhone app target.

I don't really understand what it does to my app. Do I have to change anything? I have read the [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1881/_index.html) about "Embedded Content Contains Swift". I think this setting is only for apps that are built with both Objective-C and Swift. Am I correct?

By the way, in the linked frameworks and libraries of the iOS app target, I have: iAd, StoreKit and WatchKit. The WatchKit extension and app don't link to anything. I use Xcode 6.3.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If it works, and you can submit, then you’re fine. There are no consequences of this setting being wrong that will hurt you after submission if submission succeeds.

Comment: From what I read in previous questions, people had this setting set to No and their apps still pass the submission. However, apps crashed at launch. Does it apply to this case as well?

Comment: I guess my comment requires you to have tried your app out on an actual Apple Watch. My point being, if it works on a device locally it'll work on a device post-app-store-install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to set the **Embedded Content Contains Swift** flag if you are adding a library or framework that contains Swift code, irrespective of your base-project's language (e.g.,  Swift or Objective-C).

More info here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1881/_index.html

For your situation, you **don't** have to set that flag to `yes`, as you are not linking to any external Swift libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. So added frameworks like iAd, WatchKit and StoreKit are not in Swift?

Comment: To my knowledge, those frameworks have not yet been ported to Swift, so you are correct.

Comment: The wording in that post could definitely be a bit more clear. I'll make sure to update it.